# How to compare date from java to mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Hi I want to know how we can compare a current date from java with stored date in mysql.

date stored in MySQL is `2013-01-04 13:15:00`

when i compare this date in java by getting current date

```
Date date = new Date();
```

then wrote a query if the date stored in MySQL is less than current display the result. but query is returning 0 result.

```
select model from abc model where model.abcStartDate >= date and model.abcEndDate &gt;= date
```

In the MySQL The start date and end date are of timestamp data type.

Below is the EJB entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc_table", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class ABCClass implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1924961655993587546L;

// Fields
private Date abcStartDate;
private Date abcEndDate;

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public ABCClass() {
}


@OrderBy(value="3")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "abc_start_date", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19)
public Date getabcStartDate() {
    return this.abcStartDate;
}

public void setabcStartDate(Date abcStartDate) {
    this.abcStartDate = abcStartDate;
}

@OrderBy(value="4")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "abc_end_date", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19)
public Date getabcEndDate() {
    return this.abcEndDate;
}

public void setabcEndDate(Date abcEndDate) {
    this.abcEndDate = abcEndDate;
}

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to compare date from java to mysql timestamp field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220957/how-to-compare-date-from-java-to-mysql-timestamp-field)

Answer (score 1):

One of right approach - use parametrized query in java
Use prepared statement with query

```
select model from abc model where model.abcStartDate <= ? and model.abcEndDate >= ?
```

And then set first and second params to new Date() in your java code. In this case you can compare not only current date, but any java Date you have

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the dates in SQL query using **PreparedStatement**:

```
String query="select model from abc model where model.abcStartDate >= ? and model.abcEndDate <=?;";
PreparedStatement stmnt = conn.preparedStatement(query);
stmnt.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(Calender.getInstance().getTime()));
stmnt.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(Calender.getInstance().getTime()));
stmnt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to compare date with time:
use java.sql.Timestamp for util.Date. It will work for it.
EX:
java.sql.Timestamp t = new Timestamp(Date.getTime());

Comment: hi it says The object [65464533565], of class [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].