# How to compare date from java to mysql timestamp field

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, eclipselink

Sorry for posting this same question again but i am curious to know.

I want to know how we can compare a current date from java with stored date in mysql.

date stored in MySQL is `2013-01-04 13:15:00`

when i compare this date in java by getting current date

```
Date date = new Date();
```

then wrote a query if the date stored in MySQL is less than current display the result. but query is returning 0 result in the List or an exception I have pasted the exception at the end.

```
select model from abc model where model.abcStartDate &lt;= :? and model.abcEndDate &gt;= :?
```

In ":?" date is passed
In the MySQL The start date and end date are of timestamp data type.

Below is the EJB entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "abc_table", uniqueConstraints = {})
public class ABCClass implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1924961655993587546L;

// Fields
private Date abcStartDate;
private Date abcEndDate;

// Constructors

/** default constructor */
public ABCClass() {
}


@OrderBy(value="3")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "abc_start_date", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19)
public Date getabcStartDate() {
    return this.abcStartDate;
}

public void setabcStartDate(Date abcStartDate) {
    this.abcStartDate = abcStartDate;
}

@OrderBy(value="4")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "abc_end_date", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 19)
public Date getabcEndDate() {
    return this.abcEndDate;
}

public void setabcEndDate(Date abcEndDate) {
    this.abcEndDate = abcEndDate;
}

}
```

and it throws an exception

```
Exception thrown from bean; nested exception is: Exception [EclipseLink-3001] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.2.1.v20110722-r9776): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ConversionException
Exception Description: The object [65464533565], of class [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "65464533565"
```

Answer (score 0):

Date comparison in JPQL can be done by following ways.

If you are comparing with current date & time

```
select model from abc model where model.abcStartDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
and model.abcEndDate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or create a query and pass parameter

```
query = em.createQuery("select model from abc model where model.abcStartDate >= 
:time and model.abcEndDate >= :time");
query.setParameter("time", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: what would be in CURRENT_TIMESTAMP? I have tried passing timestamp as well but it throws an exception.
    java.sql.Timestamp t = new Timestamp(date.getTime());

Comment: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP assigns current time default. u can used directly in query without any args. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597588/on-update-current-timestamp-and-jpa

Comment: Thanks vels4j. But what if i want to pass with arguments? Then I have to create a TimeStamp Object and then pass to a query? because when I do this it throws an exception.

Comment: no, its done already `query.setParameter("time", new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: @vels4j...I have tried with the solution now. it throws an exception. The object [65464533565], of class [class java.lang.String], could not be converted to [class java.lang.Integer].

Comment: sorry, I think you are doing some wrong casting and that is not related to this issue.

Comment: @vels4j...Thanks. There might be an issue in the project, so that is why might be causing this.

Comment: Include the stack trace, the error doesn't seem to have anything to do with the date, seems you have some numeric field you are storing as a varchar.